# What is the path of an MTP device in Windows?

Tags: windows, path, mtp

I am running Windows XP and have a phone mounted through USB by MTP.

In Explorer, its address is:

```
My Computer\SAMSUNG-SGH-I547\Phone\DCIM
```

I would like to execute a command line command such as

```
explorer "My Computer\SAMSUNG-SGH-I547\Phone\DCIM\Camera"
```

so as to quickly go to the Camera folder.
(Right-clicking the device or anything in it does NOT provide a "Create Shortcut" dialog.)

But "My Computer" is not a valid PATH in Windows.
Unlike USB flash drives, it seems the phone mounted by MTP does not get a letter drive name.

So, what is the path of an MTP device in Windows?

If the answer is there is no command line path, is there workaround?

Comment: This question is "How to open an MTP drive in Windows Explorer" which totally different from the question it has been marked as duplicate of. Effectively it is a duplicate of this question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397348/open-folder-on-portable-device-with-batch-file Therefore it is in my opinion linked to the wrong question as duplicate.